# How to serialize the delegate type property?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am trying to serialize a delegate into an xml file using a DataContractSerializer.
It failed with an error

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Type 'System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry' with data contract name 'DelegateSerializationHolder.DelegateEntry:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System%27) is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.

So, I wrote the DataContractResolver something like below and it fails with an exception as
System.ArgumentException : Invalid name character in '<>c'. The '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C, cannot be included in a name.

```
public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver,
            out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
        {
            var name = type.Name;
            var nameSpace = type.Namespace;

            typeName = new XmlDictionaryString(XmlDictionary.Empty, name, 0);
            if (nameSpace != null)
            {
                typeNamespace = new XmlDictionaryString(XmlDictionary.Empty, nameSpace, 0);

                if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(type.Name)) dictionary.Add(name, typeName);

                if (type.Namespace != null && !dictionary.ContainsKey(type.Namespace))
                    dictionary.Add(nameSpace, typeNamespace);

                return true;
            }

            typeName = null;
            typeNamespace = null;
            return false;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest. Any other way of serializing a delegate?

Comment: A delegate is code. Why do you want to serialize code, and more importantly, how, and how would you rehydrate that at the other end and execute it?

Comment: As @CodeCaster commented there is no sensible (or at least commonly accepted/known) way to serialize delegates/`Func<T>`/`Action<T>`/other references to running code - so you need to explicitly clarify what you expect as result to get any answer.

Comment: What people usually want, is "remote procedure call" (RPC), but the trick to that is to deploy the code to the other end first (for example in the form of a DLL), and then send a message containing the function name to call along with its parameters to said other end. There are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: I am porting some legacy library from framework 3.5 to .net standard 2.0 which used NetDataContractSerializer to serialize and deserialized. So, I am trying to replacing it with DataContractSerialzer.